# ssh ProxyCommand not working in centos but works for Ubuntu

Tags: git, ssh, proxy, centos, redhat

This is my ssh config file in ubuntu located `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host gitlab.com
    User                    git
    ProxyCommand            nc -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
```

and it works but the same config in centos doesn't work. and this is the result:

```
 git pull
Ncat: Connection timed out.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Anyway, when I run `curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:1080 icanhazip.com` the result is an IPv6.

```
ssh -xvvv git@gitlab.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for gitlab.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nc -x 127.0.0.1:1080 gitlab.com 22
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Ncat: Connection timed out.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
Host *
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
    SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
    SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
    SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

Also I tried `proxychains4 -q git pull` and it works fine

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using, and what version of OpenSSH (`ssh -V`)?

Comment: @bk2204 `OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017` and `CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)` thanks for your attention

Comment: Did you compare `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on both hosts?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks, they are different I've added the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`